How can Aquinas prove that the first mover is not only unmoved, but also unmovable?
So, basically, I think Aquinas can prove effectively that there should be a first mover. Here, I'm refering to the First Way, more specifically, for I was reading Feser's book, from which the question I'm going to ask came, but I do think this argument works for any of Aquinas' Ways.
The thing is, I have the following question: how can he prove that a first mover should be necessarily not only unmoved, but also unmovable? For if it's movable, then it has potentiality, and if it does, then it's not pure act. I mean, I do assume Aquinas was right in saying that nothing made the first mover come to exist; in fact, it doesn't have a mover himself, but only before it created other things. This does lead us to the conclusion that there wasn't potentiality in Aquinas' first mover's existence, for it was actually act (precisely because he's the first in the causal order). But even though this proves – let's assume it does, at least for now – there should be a first mover whose existence wasn't a potentiality made act, but was already act, it doesn't prove it (the mover) doesn't have any potential, nor does it prove that after creating things, it couldn't be putting towards movement by them.
Consider a father. Obviously, his son just exists because his father was his efficient cause. But this doesn't mean that, because the father was such a cause here, the product of this act can't actualize his potentials, for even though for exist, the son pressupposed the father, as soon as the son was created, turns out it could actualize the father by himself, since he already exists. I'd think the same should apply to the second cause, for if it exists, then it should have the logical right of possibly actualizing what caused it (the first mover). This, obviously, would mean the mover isn't pure act at all. An external act would be actualizing its potentials.
How does Aquinas answer to this? How can he prove that, as soon as a second cause exists (due to the first mover, it's true), this second cause can't actualize any potential in the first? He should prove it because the opposite would mean this first cause isn't pure act at all, therefore, not God. Thanks in advance.

You are using the word "actualize" in ways that leave me unsure what you mean by it; can you be more specific about that? Anyway, no, there is no necessity for a first cause. Nothing logically prevents the universe from being any mathematical object we can imagine, and we can imagine mathematical objects without first causes that extend infinitely in both directions in time, or for which time forms a closed loop. Indeed we can imagine mathematical objects without causes at all.

@causative Actualize, here, would be the metaphysical act of bringing a potential into act. Turning a ball that is green, but has the potential of becoming red, actually red by painting it, for example. About the second part: yes, we can image anything without causes. This doesn't mean 1) we didn't get these concepts from empirical reality in the first place; 2) something can exist outside of our intellect without being generated for something. Also, if it wasn't generated, it would have always existed. If it did, there would be no present, since it would require an infinite time to pass.

Then how does a son "actualize" his father, or a second cause "actualize" a first cause? Do you actualize a potential or do you actualize an entity? It seems like you're using "actualize" when you mean "affect." About (2) I feel like you didn't hear me about time being a closed loop. If time is a closed loop it could be finite. Even if time is infinite, that doesn't mean there is no present. We can easily mathematically model a particle x moving along an infinite trajectory such as x = sin(t^2), and the (say) t=3 present exists.

Another option rather than the whole universe looping (or infinite time) would be if there's an initial causal loop A -> B -> C -> A, but there's also an offshoot C -> D -> E > F -> ... so that the universe begins with a causal loop and then continues with linear time. Many options for how it could be.

@causative I didn't understand what you mean about time being a "closed loop", to be fair. About time being infinite, how do you explain the present, then? Suppose we're in a time t + 1. Time started in t, so it needed to go through one second to reach us. But it's infinite, then it already existed in t - 1; therefore, it passed through 2 seconds. The same would lead us to the fact time already was in t - 5000; that would make 5001 seconds to reach the present etc.; it'd pressuppose an infinite time passing so we can have a present. This doesn't make sense.

Regarding the son actualizing father, yes, I do mean "affect". To affect something is to make a potential state of it becoming its actuality, therefore, to actualize it. Same thing being said; I was just using Aristotle's terms. Obviously, a son can actualize a father's potential by, say, inducting him to sleep. This effectively changes the father's state, which would prove a later cause is able to affect a previous one. The same, but applied to first and second causes, can lead one to think the first cause can't be pure act.

Ah, you say an infinite timeline doesn't make sense, therefore there is no such function as f(t) = sin(t^2) ? After all how could we have f(3), when to get there we would first have to have f(2), and f(1), and f(0), and f(-1), infinitely into the past! But of course there is such a function as sin(t^2).

I don't know what such functions are. Feel free, though, to explain, logically, how it's possible. Did we pass through an infinite amount of elements? If this happened, then it wouldn't be infinite at all, for every element of it should be counted before we could get to the present. If it didn't, then we still didn't get to the present, and should keep going through every element of it until we do as such. How is present logically possible? Explain it yourself!

The idea of "us" "passing through" an infinite amount of elements is just not a rigorous notion. If you prefer, you can consider the integers ... -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... which also extend infinitely in both directions. Did "we" have to pass through infinite elements to get to -3? Do you reject negative numbers?

I don't "reject" anything; I'm asking you to explain, and since you want a "rigorous notion", how, since time necessarily has to pass an infinite amount of... time to reach in the present, then the present isn't possible. Want to count time in seconds? Do it. Reaching to the present when time always existed requires an infinite amount of seconds to pass. I don't want analogies or Mathematical expositions here, but you to explain: did these seconds pass, so time got to the present? Did an infinite amount of seconds pass so time got to this point in which we exist? Answer directly, please.

Also, when using Mathematics, one doesn't need to pass through every single element, even if the set is infinite or whatever. One just counts what is relevant to the actual situation. You will never be able to show a Mathematician passing through every single element of an "infinite" set, even though it's called infinite. It's obvious that the difference between Mathematics and the time passing is that the first one can be worked through without this necessity (of counting every single element), but the second one necessarily needs to do so.

aquinas was a scholastic philosopher. scholasticism was able to prove or disprove just about anything with its logical looking sophistry
